# Store Values from Material UI's form in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

What's the best way to store values typed into the text fields here?

```
const AddUserPage = () => (
  <div>
    <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
    <div className='main-content'>
    <form className="ROOT" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default AddUserPage;
```

I want to find a way such that I can use the stored values in my GraphQL mutations as well, without having to modify the const() structure of my page. I don't want to use the Class Component Extend or function structure here.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `const() structure`makes:

=> (This is the auto return syntax.)

If you want to store/reuse your value, you will have to define some state/variable to store the data.
You can also do it in upper component like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Parent = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ text: "" });
  return <AddUserPage value={state.text} onChange={e => setState(prev => ({ ...prev, text: e.target.value || "" }))} />
}

const AddUserPage = ({ value = "" , onChange }) => (
  <div>
    <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
    <div className='main-content'>
    <form className="ROOT" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField id="standard-basic" value={value} onChange={onChange} label="Standard" />
     // value, and Onchange comes from an upper component
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: On TypeScript, I get an error at onChange ```Type '(e: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => null'.```

Comment: I still get this at onChange ```Binding element 'onChange' implicitly has an 'any' type.```

Comment: is there any library inside your TextField component?

Comment: I'm using Material UI's TextField if that's what you mean. But never mind, I figured how to do it with ```constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);``` instead